# check if input location is adjacent to another number

Tags: python, if-statement, indexing

I have a 4x4 table to make from a list (not yet done) and I have to ask the user to input a number at a location (eg, b1,c2, column then row) but for the 2nd number (and onwards) the user has to put it adjacent to another number or else 'it is not allowed' will be displayed and it will prompt the user to input the location again. how do I do this with indexes?

I was thinking of doing

```
if above == ' ' and lower == ' ' and rightside == ' ' and leftside == ' ':
    print('Number must be placed adjacent to another number!\nPlace Where?')

else:
    continue
```

but I don't know how to write the indexes to check for the above, below, right and left >< I only know the basic things cuz I just started but here's my code

```
num_list = ['1','2','3','4','5',]
import random
num = random.choice(num_list)

table = [[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' '],
[' ', ' ', ' ', ' ']]

ss = {"W1":[0,0],
                    "W2":[1,0],
                    "W3":[2,0],
                    "W4":[3,0],
                    "X1":[0,1],
                    "X2":[1,1],
                    "X3":[2,1],
                    "X4":[3,1],
                    "Y1":[0,2],
                    "Y2":[1,2],
                    "Y3":[2,2],
                    "Y4":[3,2],
                    "Z1":[0,3],
                    "Z2":[1,3],
                    "Z3":[2,3],
                    "Z4":[3,3]}



ans = input('where would you like to place it: ')

index_ = ss[ans][0]
columns_ = ss[ans][1]
table[index_][columns_] = num
print(table)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

indexes in this senario are easy to calculate based on your if condition.But you should also check to keep the values inside the bounds of your 4x4. A function is convinient here to handle moving a step in a direction and also clipping the values

```
def moveandclip(n, x, y):
   n[0] = max(0, min(n[0] + x, 3))
   n[1] = max(0, min(n[1] + y, 3))
   return n
```

this will keep values inside the 4x4 (why 0 and 3 is used) and add the direction in the x axis and y axis given. Then it is simple to get every direction index

```
above = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,1)
below = moveandclip(ss[ans], 0 ,-1)
left = moveandclip(ss[ans], -1 ,0)
right = moveandclip(ss[ans], 1 ,0)
```

Comment: Hello! thank you I tried it out and it works :D but I don't really understand the def portion? I get that it's meant to keep it in my 4x4 but how does it work?

Comment: Well i assume u undrestand the basic function syntax, now for the logic part, u can split into more lines to make it easier to understand. what is happening first is we add the offset given by the direction to a number n. after that we use min to find if the number got over 3, because it will be 4 and the min of 3 and 4 is always 3, after that we also check if the number was 0 and we subtract one making it -1 and since max of 0 and -1 is 0. so when the number goes outside the 0-3 allowed values we bring it back. if not it remains the same plus the offset. and we have 2 numbers so double that

Comment: ohh I understand it better now, thank you so much!! 